# Biopython's SeqIO.parse stops parsing after the first iteration. Why? Is this a problem with my installation?

Tags: python, loops, biopython

I have two fasta files (see below for reproducible example) and I need to compare all the sequences in the first file against all the sequences in the second file. This is a basic operation that the following code should be able to perform:

```
testbiopython.py 

# Import necessary modules from Biopython
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

# Define the filenames of the FASTA files
fasta_file1 = "testfasta1.fasta"
fasta_file2 = "testfasta2.fasta"

# Parse the sequences in the FASTA files
fasta_seqs1 = SeqIO.parse(fasta_file1, "fasta")
fasta_seqs2 = SeqIO.parse(fasta_file2, "fasta")

#Loop thorugh the files
for fasta_seq1 in fasta_seqs1:
    print(fasta_seq1.id)
    for fasta_seq2 in fasta_seqs2:
        print(fasta_seq1.id + " " + fasta_seq2.id)
```

However, when I run this loop `python testbiopython.py`, I only get one pass through fasta_seqs2 and the script closes after the first iteration.

```
Seq1
Seq1 Seq5
Seq1 Seq6
Seq1 Seq7
Seq1 Seq8
Seq2
Seq3
Seq4
```

Why? How can I correct this behavior? Furthermore, what can it be done to avoid loading the whole files into memory (for files that are much larger than my example files).

Sample fasta files to reproduce the example:

```
#testfasta1.fasta
>Seq1
AAAAAAA
>Seq2
CCCCCCC
>Seq3
GGGGGGG
>Seq4
TTTTTT
```

```
#testfasta2.fasta
>Seq5
AAAAAAA
>Seq6
CCCCCCC
>Seq7
GGGGGGG
>Seq8
TTTTTT
```

Comment: The return value of `SeqIO.parse()` is evidently a *generator* - once you've iterated through all of its values, it has no further values to give you.  You either need to reload the file used in the inner loop (probably not the most efficient idea), or do `fasta_seqs2 = list(fasta_seqs2)` to convert this generator to a list that can be iterated as many times as you want (at the cost of having the entire sequence in memory).

Comment: your edit changes the question from a minor change, to a much larger problem that strongly depends on the details of your algorithms and data.  you'd need to give a lot more details than you have, and even then would likely be closed as off-topic because there isn't one good answer.  useful details to include would be want to do with the sequences from each file and the expected sizes of each file.

Comment: Can you give more context on the bioinformatics problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know BioPython, but presumably `SeqIO.parse` is returning an iterator over sequences.  This iterator gets exhausted by the nested loop, and subsequent passes see nothing.  You should instead store the result into some data structure, e.g. a `list`, so that you can iterate from the beginning each time.

For example, changing your code to just do:

```
fasta_seqs2 = list(SeqIO.parse(fasta_file2, "fasta"))
```

might be enough.

Note, if you're doing lots of comparisons there are data structures that would mean you don't need to compare against everything in this second file.  The details would depend on how you're doing the comparison, e.g. is it exact or approximate.  But it's worth doing some reading around if your second file contains more than a few thousand sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that after the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop has reached the end of the `fasta_seqs2` then there's no more data to read. Just convert the `fasta_seqs2` iterator to a list so you can loop multiple time.

```
edit: to load file progressively, create a function that returns a new iterator for the second file each time it is called

# Import necessary modules from Biopython
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

# Define the filenames of the FASTA files
fasta_file1 = "testfasta1.fasta"
fasta_file2 = "testfasta2.fasta"

# Function to create a new iterator for the second file
def get_fasta_seqs2():
    return SeqIO.parse(fasta_file2, "fasta")

# Parse the sequences in the first FASTA file
fasta_seqs1 = SeqIO.parse(fasta_file1, "fasta")

# Loop through the files
for fasta_seq1 in fasta_seqs1:
    print(fasta_seq1.id)
    fasta_seqs2 = get_fasta_seqs2()  # Get a new iterator for the second file
    for fasta_seq2 in fasta_seqs2:
        print(fasta_seq1.id + " " + fasta_seq2.id)
```

Comment: This solves the problem for small files. Now the problem is that my files are too big to be hold on memory at once. Is there a way to progressively load the file?

Comment: note that if the files are too large to hold in memory then this is going to take an inordinate amount of time to execute.  e.g. smaller pair of files FASTA files each containing a 100k sequences each, if it takes 1millisecond to compare sequences then it would take 115 days to iterate over each pair. i.e. 100k ** 2 / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24.  these will likely be big enough to hold in memory, so bigger files will take significantly longer